# why my attempt of finding time complexity of three nested loops is wrong?

Tags: time-complexity

```
for ( i = 1; i <= n ; i++){
  for (j = 1; j <= n ; j += i ){
    for (k = 1; k <= n ; k++){
      //basic_step ;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my attempt :

```
\sum\_{i=1}^{n}\sum\_{j=1}^{\frac{n}{i}}\sum\_{k=1}^{n}1\\to \sum\_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n^2}{i}\longrightarrow n^2 \sum\_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$$
\textbf{   and from here I assumed that k=log(i) which means} $$2^k=i$$ \textbf{ and the sum will look like that }$$
\n^2 sum\_{k=0}^{log(n)}\frac{1}{2^k}$$ \textbf{ which is for sure greater than}$$n^2$$ \textbf {and if we tend the sum to infinty and not just log(n) we get } $$n^2\sum\_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2^k} \le 2n^2$$
\text{ and now its obviously } $$T(n) \in \theta(n^2)$$
\text{ for some reason its wrong and I'm here to ask what did I do wrong?}
\text{ pleas NOTE : I'm looking for the}$$ \theta $$ \text{ notation and the Big-O and if opur answer will include any Integrals please just don't do it I'm not allowed to do it }
\text{ thanks }
```

Comment: it seems my attempt is not looking as expected can any correct the Math LaTex here please

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about software programming but about more abstract mathematical concepts. It may be more on-topic on https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also, TeX formatting is supported there.

Comment: sorry for this I posted in the other forum thanks for leading me to it